# Using awk with variables

Tags: shell, awk

```
x=3
A=`echo $A|awk '{print $x}'`
echo $A
```

doesnt print 3. How can i use variables with awk*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass variables to `awk` with the `-v` flag.

```
x=3
A=`echo $A|awk -v y=$x '{print y}'`
echo $A
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the variables of shell by this way:   `"'$your-shell-variable'"` or `'$your-shell-variable'`. The former considers the variable as string, while the later considers it as number. The following is the code you want:

```
x=3    
A=`echo $A|awk '{print "'$x'"}'`    
echo $A
```

Answer (score 2):

Uh, what's the point of echoing `$A`? It just creates a useless fork and pipe.

```
x=3
A=`awk -v y=$x 'BEGIN {print y}'`
echo $A
```

And while I'm at it, this seems like a convoluted and expensive way to write `A=$x` :-)