# AWK working with variables, not files

Tags: awk

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373379/using-awk-with-variables), but I cannot figure out how to make what I need.
I have a variable, which is a path, so I would like to have the name of the file (last column if I separate by `/`).

So I tried several combinations, such as:

```
#!/bin/sh

source=$1
target=$2


for i in "$source"/*
do
    $name = awk -F/ -v '{ print $NF }' $i
    echo $name
done
```

But no success, could anybody help me?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use the shell to extract the file names without external tools

```
for file in $source/*
do
  echo ${file##*/}
done
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit unclear... You would like to extract the filename from a path?

to get path without file-name use `dirname`:

```
$ dirname /usr/bin/foo.bar
/usr/bin
```

to get file-name without path use `basename`

```
$ basename /usr/bin/foo.bar
foo.bar
```

Using awk:

```
$ echo $a 
/usr/bin/foo.bar  

$ echo $a | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' 
foo.bar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the file name, then use basename as Fredrik suggested. Here is a solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

source=$1
target=$2

for i in "$source"/*
do
    name=$(basename $i)
    echo $name
done
```

This solution works, but it has a bug: if either a directory or file contains space in its name, then it does not work correctly. Here is my revised solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

source=$1
target=$2

pushd "$source" >/dev/null 2>&1
for name in *
do
    echo $name
done
popd >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Note that I use pushd/popd to get into and out of the source directory. Since I am already in the source directory, I don't need to call basename.