# How to pass variable to awk

Tags: shell, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using awk with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373379/using-awk-with-variables)

The following command is wrong, the point is I want to use `$curLineNumber` in awk, how can I do it? Any solution?

```
curLineNumber = 3
curTime=`ls -l | awk 'NR==$curLineNumber {print $NF}'`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curTime=$(ls -l | awk -v line=$curLineNumber 'NR == line { print $NF }'
```

The `-v` option is used to specify variables initialized on the command line.  I chose the name `line` for the `awk` variable.