# pass some variables to awk

Tags: shell, awk

I want to write a bash and pass some variables to it.

```
awk -v $3=lengthA -v $4=lengthB 'NF<=lengthA/lengthB' - >
```

But it returns this error

awk: fatal: `50' is not a legal variable name

Comment: see e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943721/how-to-pass-variable-to-awk?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$3` is from the shell, then

```
awk -v var=$3 'NF<=var' file
```

If you like to use a shell variable then

```
lengthA=3
awk -v var="$lengthA" 'NF<=var' file
```

or

```
awk 'NF<=var' var="$lengthA" file
```

PS always use double quote with variable.

Answer (score 2):

The argument `-v` requires `name=value`. So you need to write `-v lengthA=$3`