# Passing bash input variables to awk

Tags: bash, awk

Trying to pass a variable into awk from user input:

Have tried variations of awk -v with errors stating 'awk: invalid -v option', even though the option is listed in man files.

```
#! /bin/bash
read -p "Enter ClassID:" CLASS
read -p "Enter FacultyName:" FACULTY


awk '/FacultyName/ {print}' data-new.csv > $FACULTY.csv
awk -vclass=${CLASS} '/class/ {print}' data-new.csv >> $FACULTY.csv 


echo Class is $CLASS
echo Faculty member is $FACULTY
```

Comment: Try removing the space in `#! /bin/bash`

Comment: check this: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/passing-bash-variable-to-awk.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using awk with variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373379/using-awk-with-variables)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some versions of awk require a space between the `-v` and the variable assignment. Also, you should put the bash variable in double-quotes to prevent unwanted parsing by the shell (e.g. word splitting, wildcard expansion) before it's passed to awk. Finally, in awk `/.../` is a constant regular expression (i.e. `/class/` will search for the string "class", not the value of the variable "class"). With all of this corrected, here's the awk command that I think will do what you want:

```
awk -v class="${CLASS}" '$0 ~ class {print}' data-new.csv >> $FACULTY.csv
```

Now, is there any reason you're using this instead of:

```
grep "$CLASS" data-new.csv >> $FACULTY.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it worked. I am very new to programming with awk and bash, the learning curve is a bit steep for me but this helps move my knowledge along. The grep command I have some experience, however, I am still enough of a newbie not to know the best method, at the very least, I wanted to learn about awk. Thanks to everyone else for replying.

Answer (score 2):

Your script is not clear to me, but these all work:

```
CLASS=ec123
echo | awk -vclass=$CLASS '{print class}'
echo | awk -vclass=${CLASS} '{print class}'
```