# AWK - passing generated string as code for awk from command line

Tags: bash, unix, awk, ksh

I am trying to dynamically print selected fields of a file using `awk`.

Basically, the question is why this one works:

```
awk -F';' '{print $3 ";" $4 ";" }' file
```

but this does not:

```
awk -F';' '{print '`echo '$3 ";" $4 ";"'`' }' file
```

My final goal is to encapsulate the above in one command so that I would be able to do

```
my_cmd ';' 3 6 7 8 file(s)
```

which should display the fields `#3,6,7,8` delimited by `;` from `file(s)`.

*Editing my post:*
Found out myself that my problem was echo was inserting of course a new line caracter which was causing issue for awk :o) 
\c did the trick, also some \" escaping had to do (see below).

```
awk -F';' '{print '"`echo '$3 \";\" $4 \";\"\c'`"' }' file(s)
```

Now I'm only left to change it with command which will generate dinamically a string like 
`$2 ";' $5 ";' $6 ";' $9 ";"` (number and fields should be the intput) etc. which should go between `'{print '` and `' }'`

Thanks to cbuckley I found out my one line command: (Issue solved).

```
cut -d"$1" -f `shift; echo $* | sed 's/[^ 0-9]\{1,\}.*$//;s/[ ]$//;s/[ ]\{1,\}/,/g'` `shift; printf "%s\n" $(echo $*) | grep -v '^[0-9]$'`
```

here $* are the input parameters and if above would be as an alias or a function in your .rc file named say filterc then the synopsys would be:

```
filterc delimiter column1 [column2 [column3...]] file1 [file2 [file3...]]
```

where:

delimiter - one char only

column1..n - a number representing the column

file1..n - files to be filtered, assumption here that files will not have names from 
numbers only and that all are of same format.

Comment: `echo` and reverse tilde has no meaning inside awk. You should better explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: To pass shell variables to `awk` you need to use the `-v` parameter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373379/using-awk-with-variables

Comment: test what you did: `echo '{print ...}'` (bloody syntax highlight doesn't let me write the full code)

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs. Looks like found itself what was the issue: echo was adding a \n after it was executed which caused the line to be broken : } was not present to close the statement for awk.
Also some tweakinings had to do to finaly get it work
    
        awk -F';' '{print '"`echo '$3 \";\" $4 \";\"\c'`"' }'

Comment: @vadimbog don't do that, it's completely the wrong approach, whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @EdMorton What exactly is completly wrong? Above works exactly as I wanted. Can you elaborate from which perspective it is completely wrong?

Comment: Software that produces the output you want given a specific sample input set is the starting point towards finding a solution. It is not necessarily a good solution. In this case at a minimum you're opening yourself up to inconsistent echo implementations, arguments that may expand to awk code that causes bizarre errors, complicated quoting issues, potential globbing and word splitting issues, etc. And it's all 100% unnecessary when you can simply pass awk a string of the fields you want printed and let it do that.

Comment: I totaly agree that its kind of a perverse thing to do the way I did and that I get some unnecesary complexity. I just wanted to achieve my task with one line command so that I could incorporate in my own shell mark tool which will allow me to give a name to all that line and then just refer to it as a short name (just by passing needed aparameters to it).

Comment: @vadimbog The wrapper command does nothing more than slightly alter the way of passing options to `cut` (and not for the better, IMO). Since `cut` already takes `-d` and `-f` options as well as multiple files, why not just use `cut` directly?

Comment: @cbuckley not to remember the option names necessary for cut. I find it easier if i have a dedicated command which gets just the parameters values without specifying anything extra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command sounds very similar to `cut`:

```
cut -d ';' -f 1,3 <<EOT
one;two;three
foo;bar;quux
EOT

one;three
foo;quux

cut -d '-' -f 2,4 <<EOT
one-two-three-four
five-six-seven-eight
EOT

two-four
six-eight
```

Comment: Heh, yeah that's preferable (unless you are dealing with multi-character delimiters which `cut` doesn't do), *+1*.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are after?

```
#!/bin/bash

get_columns()
{
    local fs=$1; shift
    local _awk=
    local column

    for column; do
        _awk="${_awk}\$${column},"
    done
    awk -F"$fs" -v OFS="$fs" "{ print ${_awk%,} }"
}

get_columns ';' 1 3 <<EOT
one;two;three
foo;bar;quux
EOT

get_columns '-' 2 4 <<EOT
one-two-three-four
five-six-seven-eight
EOT
```

-

```
$ ./t.sh
one;three
foo;quux
two-four
six-eight
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function my_cmd {
    fs="$1"
    shift
    eval file="\$$#"
    awk -F"$fs" -v flds="$*" '
        BEGIN{ n=split(flds,f,/ /) }
        {
           for (i=1; i<n; i++)
               printf "%s%s", (i>1?FS:""), $(f[i])
           print ""
        }
    ' "$file"
}

$ cat file
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h

$ my_cmd ';' 3 6 7 8 file                                                     
c;f;g;h

$ my_cmd ';' 6 3 8 file  
f;c;h
```

Comment: How to adjust above if more than one file to give as input?

Comment: Add code above the awk script to separate file names from non-file-names. Since any number can be a file name, I don't know how you plan to separate them.