# Awk field variable clash with function argument

Tags: bash, awk

My function receives variable as argument, for example:

```
function do()
{
  eval "TEST=$1"
}
```

Now I want to parse some data in the same function:

```
function do()
{
   eval "TEST=$1"
   tail -n+3 file.txt | awk '$1  ~ "[0-9]$" {print "/dev/"$1}'
}
```

The problem is awk clashes its own field separators "$1" with argument passed to function.
Is there a way to work around it without using global variable as argument?

Comment: Within single quotes, the `$1` means field one in awk.

Comment: `eval` isn't necessary here; use `declare "TEST=$1"` instead.

Comment: see `-v` option to pass a variable to awk script

Comment: Actually, it's not clear why `TEST=$1` isn't sufficient.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using awk with variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373379/using-awk-with-variables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-v` option to declare an `awk` variable holding the value of the function argument.

```
function do()
{
   TEST=$1
   tail -n+3 file.txt | awk -v test="$TEST"  '$1 ~ /[0-9]$/ {print "/dev/"test}'
}
```

Comment: The regexp delimiter in awk is `/`, not `"`. You'd only use `"`-delimited strings in an RE context if you have a specific goal in mind and fully understand the caveats. That doesn't apply in this case so you should change the test to `$1 ~ /[0-9]$/`.