# Bash function with input fails awk command

Tags: linux, string, bash, function, awk

I am writing a function in a BASH shell script, that should return lines from csv-files with headers, having more commas than the header. This can happen, as there are values inside these files, that could contain commas. For quality control, I must identify these lines to later clean them up. What I have currently:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

get_bad_lines () {
    local correct_no_of_commas=$(head -n 1 $1/$1_0_0_0.csv | tr -cd , | wc -c)
    local no_of_files=$(ls $1 | wc -l)
    for i in $(seq 0 $(( ${no_of_files}-1 )))
    do
        # Check that the file exist
        if [ ! -f "$1/$1_0_${i}_0.csv" ]; then
            echo "File: $1_0_${i}_0.csv not found!"
            continue
        fi
        # Search for error-lines inside the file and print them out
        echo "$1_0_${i}_0.csv has over $correct_no_of_commas commas in the following lines:"
        grep -o -n '[,]' "$1/$1_0_${i}_0.csv" | cut -d : -f 1 | uniq -c | awk '$1 > $correct_no_of_commas {print}'
    done
}

get_bad_lines products
get_bad_lines users
```

The output of this program is now all the comma-counts with all of the line numbers in all the files,
and I suspect this is due to the input `$1` (foldername, i.e. products & users) conflicting with the call to `awk` with reference to `$1` as well (where I wish to grab the first column being the count of commas for that line in the current file in the loop).

Is this the issue? and if so, would it be solvable by either referencing the 1.st column or the folder name by different variable names instead of both of them using `$1` ?

Example, current output:

```
      5 6667
      5 6668
      5 6669
      5 6670
```

(should only show lines for that file having more than 5 commas).

Tried variable declaration in call to awk as well, with same effect
(as in the accepted answer to [Awk field variable clash with function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385925/awk-field-variable-clash-with-function-argument))
:

```sh
get_bad_lines () {
    local table_name=$1
    local correct_no_of_commas=$(head -n 1 $table_name/${table_name}_0_0_0.csv | tr -cd , | wc -c)
    local no_of_files=$(ls $table_name | wc -l)
    for i in $(seq 0 $(( ${no_of_files}-1 )))
    do
        # Check that the file exist
        if [ ! -f "$table_name/${table_name}_0_${i}_0.csv" ]; then
            echo "File: ${table_name}_0_${i}_0.csv not found!"
            continue
        fi
        # Search for error-lines inside the file and print them out
        echo "${table_name}_0_${i}_0.csv has over $correct_no_of_commas commas in the following lines:"
        grep -o -n '[,]' "$table_name/${table_name}_0_${i}_0.csv" | cut -d : -f 1 | uniq -c | awk -v table_name="$table_name" '$1 > $correct_no_of_commas {print}'
    done
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Zilog80 . I was a bit unclear: the values inside the CSV files do not contain quotation marks, but a single value might have one or more commas inside. It makes it difficult to know which value corresponds to which field, without manual inspection.

Comment: In a correctly formatted CSV files, commas (or newlines) inside a field are not a problem, because the CSV format provides quoting rules for such cases, and they should not cause any trouble. For instance, a CSV line `FOO,"BAR,BAZ",BOOM` has 3 fields, the second one being _BAR,BAZ_.

Comment: @user1934428 , you are right. Unfortunately, I am receiving incorrectly formatted CSV files, without quotes, e.g. `FOO,BAR,BAZ,BOOM`, where `BAR,BAZ` corresponds to a single field

Comment: @GustavRasmussen: If you **know** that such fields are always formatted incorrectly, you could simply count the commas in the lines and pick those lines which have an incorrect number. If some lines **may** have incorrect formatting, and others have their comma-fields formatted correctly, the simplemst approach IMO would be to use a CSV parser.

Comment: The `grep -o -n '[,]'`  command will return the first comma match for each line where you expect all the matching commas in the line. As you need to strictly count the number of comma, you should go full `awk` with `awk -v table_name="$table_name"  -v num_comma=$correct_no_of_commas '/,/ {if (gsub(/,/, ",")>num_comma) print($0);}' "$table_name/${table_name}_0_${i}_0.csv"`. You could also check in the `awk` script if the file meets incorrect number of comma and then only output the concerned files.

Comment: @user1934428 yes, that makes sense. I would also like to learn why my awk command fails to produce my expected outcome, is it clashing it's 1.st column with the function input for example? And how can it get fixed ?

Comment: @Zilog80 This is the kind of functionality I am hoping for. You can turn it into an answer if you like, so that I may accept it. Could you please have a look, if my original script was creating some clash between the `$1` reference ? I use it both as function input as well as trying to refer to the first column with awk. Finally, in your proposed solution, how may I add the line-number as a left-most column, next to the line-content ? (only for lines, where there are too many commas).

Comment: @Zilog80 added line number by replacing `print($0)` with `print(NR":"$0)`. Would still love to learn why the original awk command failed to give only lines with too many commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` the full way to achieve that :

```sh
get_bad_lines () {
  find "$1" -maxdepth 1  -name "$1_0_*_0.csv" | while read -r my_file ; do
    awk -v table_name="$1" '
        NR==1 { num_comma=gsub(/,/, ""); }  
        /,/ { if (gsub(/,/, ",", $0) > num_comma) wrong_array[wrong++]=NR":"$0;}
        END { if (wrong > 0) {
                print(FILENAME" has over "num_comma" commas in the following lines:");
                for (i=0;i<wrong;i++) { print(wrong_array[i]); }
              } 
            }' "${my_file}"
  done
}
```

For why your original awk command failed to give only lines with too many commas, that is because you are using a shell variable *correct_no_of_commas* inside a single quoted `awk` statement (`'$1 > $correct_no_of_commas {print}'`). Thus there no substitution by the shell, and `awk` read *"$correct_no_of_commas"* as is, and perceives it as an undefined variable. More precisely, `awk` look for the variable *correct_no_of_commas* which is undefined in the `awk` script so it is an empty string . `awk` will then execute `$1 > $""` as matching condition, and  as *$""* is a *$0* equivalent, `awk` will compare the count in $1 with the full input line. From a numerical point of view, the full input line has the form `<tab><count><tab><num_line>,` so it is 0 for `awk`. Thus, `$1 > $correct_no_of_commas` will be always true.

Comment: Thanks, @Zilog80 , this is what I want. There seem to be a few syntax issues , ran it through `https://www.shellcheck.net/` , with output: `$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 1:
get_bad_lines () {
^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this function.
^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this brace group. Fix to allow more checks.
Line 2:
awk -v table_name="$1" (
^-- SC1036: '(' is invalid here. Did you forget to escape it?
^-- SC1056: Expected a '}'. If you have one, try a ; or \n in front of it.
^-- SC1072: Missing '}'. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.`

Comment: My bad, there was a typo, the parenthesis should have been a single quote in first line. You can use also `function get_bad_lines () {` for bash or keep `get_bad_lines () {` for POSIX compliance.

Comment: Thanks, @Zilog80 , this fixed the linting issues. Now I am getting another one for the filename wildcard though: `awk: fatal: cannot open file `medications/medications_0_*_0.csv' for reading (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Fixed it with a for loop going through all the files, around your function body.

Comment: My bad again, i have wrongly double quoted the awk file param, thinking "one file" . I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I really appreciate it

Comment: @GustavRasmussen Updated the answer regarding multiple files.

Answer (score 2):

You can identify all the bad lines with a single awk command

```sh
awk -F, 'FNR==1{print FILENAME; headerCount=NF;} NF>headerCount{print} ENDFILE{print "#######\n"}' /path/here/*.csv
```

If you want the line number also to be printed, use this

```sh
awk -F, 'FNR==1{print FILENAME"\nLine#\tLine"; headerCount=NF;} NF>headerCount{print FNR"\t"$0} ENDFILE{print "#######\n"}' /path/here/*.csv
```

Comment: Getting error: `awk: can't open file /my_path/*.csv
 source line number 1`. The wildcard character `*` does not expand to the file names. Why is that and how can it be fixed ?

Comment: Can you provide the full command you're trying to run? I've checked this working on MacOS and Ubuntu.

Comment: `folders=(my_path my_path_2);
for folder in $folders
do
  awk -F, 'FNR==1{print FILENAME; headerCount=NF;} NF>headerCount{print} ENDFILE{print "#######\n"}' /$folder/*.csv
done`

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. There was a forward slash in front of the folder name. After removing it, it now works. (Changed `/$folder/*.csv` into `$folder/*.csv`)

Comment: Please run as `awk -F, 'FNR==1{print FILENAME; headerCount=NF;} NF!=headerCount{print} ENDFILE{print "#######\n"}' my_path/*.csv my_path_2/*.csv`

Comment: Currently the code looks for rows which are having more columns than header. You might also want to consider lesser no of columns and change the condition to `NF != headerCount`